# Defining PATH in AC_SEARCH_LIBS

Tags: linux, autotools, configure, netcdf

I'm trying to create a m4 file in which I want to search a netCDF library in a certain location.

This is the code I'm doing:

```
AC_DEFUN([AX_CHECK_NETCDF],[

  AC_ARG_WITH([netcdf],
        [AS_HELP_STRING([--with-netcdf=DIR], [use netCDF library from directory DIR])],
        netcdf_prefix="$with_netcdf"
        []
        )

  AS_IF([test x$netcdf_prefix != x],
        [NETCDF_LDFLAGS="-L$netcdf_prefix/lib" 
        NETCDF_CPPFLAGS="-I$netcdf_prefix/include"],
        [AC_MSG_ERROR([])]
       )

  ax_have_netcdf=yes
  AC_SEARCH_LIBS([nc_open], [netcdf], [], [ax_have_netcdf=no])
  AC_CHECK_HEADERS([netcdf.h], [], [ax_have_netcdf=no])

  AS_IF([test "x$ax_have_netcdf" = xyes],
       [AC_SUBST([NETCDF_LDFLAGS])
        AC_SUBST([NETCDF_CPPFLAGS])
       $1],
       [$2])
  ]
)
```

The problem is that I don't know how to force AC_SEARCH_LIBS to look for lnetcdf only in the path specified by netcdf_prefix.

What is happening now is that the netcdf library is searched in the library system folders.

Thanks!